# trait not satisfied for select(count_star()).first

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'd like to do a count on records of a table named topics. I'm doing it almost by the [book](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/dsl/fn.count_star.html)

but when I do

```rust
let count: u64 = topics.select(count_star()).first(&conn).unwrap();
```

I keep getting (.first is underlined as error):

```
[rustc E0277] [E] the trait bound `u64: diesel::deserialize::FromSql<diesel::
sql_types::BigInt, diesel::mysql::Mysql>` is not satisfied

the trait `diesel::deserialize::FromSql<diesel::sql_types::BigInt, diesel::
mysql::Mysql>` is not implemented for `u64`

help: the following implementations were found:
    <u64 as diesel::deserialize::FromSql<diesel::sql_types::
// I guess there's more information but Vim's
// Pmenu only shows up to eight lines.
```

So propably I need to do some type casting here, but honestly, I have no idea at which point.

Comment: Please include a [reprex].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error tells you, count_star generates a [BigInt](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/sql_types/struct.BigInt.html).

And as BigInt's documentation indicates, BigInt is convertible to and from i64, not u64.

I guess despite MySQL having unsigned integers Diesel doesn't support them because SQL doesn't specify unsigned integers, so not all database engines have them (e.g. Postgres does not).

Anyway your `count` should be an `i64`, or you need to set up a more explicit conversion from a `BigInt` to an `i64` to an `u64`.