# Rust diesel facing error when trying to get total count from table

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am implementing a database using rust `diesel`. I want to get the total count or the total number of columns that exist in a table using a query with the `filter` condition. Below is my table structure and query code. I am not using any `BIGINT,` big decimal in my table structure.

> the trait bound `i32: FromSql<BigInt, Pg>` is not satisfied
> the following implementations were found:
> <i32 as FromSql<Integer, DB>>
> required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Queryable<BigInt, Pg>` for `i32`
> required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<PooledConnection<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>, i32>` for

```
#Emplyee table

| employee-id  | employee_name | empolyee_email|       
| -----------  | --------------|-------------  |
| 1            | ABC           |abc@mail.com   |
| 2            | xyz           |xyz@mail.com   |


# Account table

| account  | employee-id    | account-balnce | created_at|
| -------- | ----------     |--------------- |-----------|
| 1        | 1              |   2000         | 22/10/2021|
| 2        | 2              |   5000         | 01/09/2021|
```

```
fn get_total_accounts(&self, employee_id: &str) -> anyhow::Result<Option<i32>> {
        let res: i32 = employee::table
            .inner_join(account::table)
            .filter(employee::dsl::employee_id.eq(employee_id))
            .count()
            .get_result(&self.pool.get()?)?;  //get_result through error
               
 }
```

Comment: Per its [documentation](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/query_dsl/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#method.get_result) the `get_result` function returns a `QueryResult<U>`, which cannot be assigned to a variable of i32 directly. I think that is the cause.

Comment: As the error says, the query will return a `BigInt`, which can't be converted to `i32` (`i32: FromSql<BigInt, Pg> not satisfied`). You'll need to use `u64` instead of `i32`. The query will return a `BigInt` because you are doing a `.count()` query, which will return the number of matching rows, which may be a large number, irrespective of whether any `BigInt`-like type is used in any table.

Comment: u64 also same error `the trait bound `u64: FromSql<BigInt, Pg>` is not satisfied
required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Queryable<BigInt, Pg>` for `u64`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<PooledConnection<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>, u64>` for `

Comment: using I64 solved my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trait not satisfied for select(count\_star()).first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64459198/trait-not-satisfied-for-selectcount-star-first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using I64 solved my issue.

```
fn get_total_accounts(&self, employee_id: &str) -> anyhow::Result<Option<i32>> {
        let res: i64 = employee::table
            .inner_join(account::table)
            .filter(employee::dsl::employee_id.eq(employee_id))
            .count()
            .get_result(&self.pool.get()?)?;  //get_result through error
               
 }
```